# Android ListView setBackground for all Items when clicked

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I'm set a background for the item, that was clicked.

```
list  = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    //ListView parent, View v, int position, long id 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
});
```

The Problem is, when i click on a another item, the last item and the new item will be habe the Color Red. Is it possible to set the Color Red for the last item back (or for all) in the setOnItemClickListener?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you want multi select listview?

Comment: Yes, i want it use for multi

Comment: Sorry for the late. I didn't see your comment. Please see this link it will help you.

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/11/implement-custom-multi-select-listview.html

and also

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-multiple-selection-listview/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, create a custom background drawable using selector tag in xml and add it as a background to you child layout.

see this for more information :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Answer (score 0):

the problem  is their is required to remove background from the previous view so you need to get previous itemview and remove background from that view and in the current view set background.

1. if you want to reset your list view than you have to do in the looping.

or

1. you have to store previous selected item position somehow. than on the click time you can do remove background.you can get previous set item IE.

   ```
   public View previousItemView(){ 
       int wantedPosition =  childPosition;
   // This is the same as child #0
   int firstPosition = parent.getFirstVisiblePosition();
   int wantedChild = wantedPosition - firstPosition;
   // Say, first visible position is 8, you want position 10, wantedChild
   // will now be 2
   // So that means your view is child #2 in the ViewGroup:
   if (wantedChild < 0 || wantedChild >= parent.getChildCount()) {
       convertView = null;
     } else {
       // Could also check if wantedPosition is between
       // listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() and
       // listView.getLastVisiblePosition() instead.
       convertView = parent.getChildAt(wantedChild);
     }
     return convertView;
   }
   ```

Comment: But can i use this on Fragment?